# Mojolicious route with a parameter not matching if the parameter contains %2f

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

I have the following route

```
  $r->get('/select_folder/:mail')->to('mail#change_folder');
```

It works well almost every time but when the route contains the %2f sequence of characters, equivalent to / it works as if %2f is a path separatator instead of a escaped sequence.

This is an example input:

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/select_folder/%5bGmail%5d%2fDestacados

This is part of the error:

> None of these routes could generate a response for your GET request for /select_folder/[Gmail]/Destacados, maybe you need to add a new one?

I would like to know some way to get a parameter like this as an url part without using GET or POST parameters.

Comment: I have seen the %2f transformation to / is the intended behavior in a laravel issue...https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22125 Anyway I would like to avoid the usage of GET parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [wildcard placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Guides::Routing#Wildcard-placeholders) to allow `/` to be part of the matched parameter.

```
  $r->get('/select_folder/*mail')->to('mail#change_folder');
```

The reason why %2F is interpreted as a `/` is because the URL is decoded before being applied to routing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have discovered how to use regular expressions to solve the problem.

```
$r->get('/select_folder/:folder'=>[folder=>qr/.*/])->to('mail#change_folder');
```

I made :folder match any character, now it is working.